# How to calculate the sum of multiple confusion matrix in Python?

Tags: python, list, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I have stored the results of 5 confusion matrix in an array. Now I have to calculate the sum of confusion matrix and then I want to use to calculate for True positive, False positive, False negative and True negative.  Following is the code that I am using:

```
cm_decision_tree = []

cm_decision_tree.append(confusion_matrix(y_test, decision_tree_pred))

print (cm_decision_tree)

[array([[ 0,  9],
        [ 4, 2]], dtype=int64),
 array([[ 4,  6],
        [1, 6]], dtype=int64),
 array([[ 1, 10],
        [ 0, 9]], dtype=int64),
 array([[ 4, 14],
        [ 5, 5]], dtype=int64),
 array([[ 0, 14],
        [ 7, 2]], dtype=int64)]

matrix_result_average=cm_decision_tree.mean(axis=0)
```

When I try to calculate the mean of this result by using above piece of code I get this error

```
1 from statistics import mean
2 matrix_result_average=cm_decision_tree.mean(axis=0)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

My expected result is to calculate True positive, False positive, False negative and True negative from the sum of multiple confusion matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Given that [`sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix) returns an `np.ndarray`, your object `cm_decision_tree` represents a `list` of `numpy.ndarray`'s. To calculate the sum of the confusion matrices, you can do:

```
cm_decision_tree_summed = np.sum(cm_decision_tree, axis=0)
print(cm_decision_tree_summed)
# [[ 9 53]
#  [17 24]]
```

Please note that this summed confusion matrix inherently contains True Positives, False Positives and the like, which is why there is nothing additional to compute.

Code used to replicate the error:

```
import numpy as np

matrix_1 = np.array(
    [[0, 9],[4, 2]]
)
matrix_2 = np.array(
    [[4, 6], [1, 6]]
)
matrix_3 = np.array(
    [[1, 10], [0, 9]]
)
matrix_4 = np.array(
    [[4, 14], [5, 5]]
)
matrix_5 = np.array(
    [[0, 14], [7, 2]]
)

cm_decision_tree = [matrix_1, matrix_2, matrix_3, matrix_4, matrix_5]

matrix_result_average=cm_decision_tree.mean(axis=0)  # AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'mean'
```